# How to add an event on a menu in C# project?

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Forms App that contain a menu bar.
I want to display a Help Message when I press on the "HELP" menu button.

All that I can see when I press view code is this:

```
private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I think that I need to create inside the function a MessageBox or an event that will display the desired message.
Do you have any idea how should I do this, please?

Comment: Deciding which programming language you're using would be a good first step.  As for the question itself, have you tried anything at all?  Is there some reason why `MessageBox.Show()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well, I selected Windows Forms App from the C# dropdown, but when I press on "view code" on my design, it appears that.

Comment: this is definitely not that difficult.. do you understand the basics of the C# language..?

Comment: @Marko: Ok, so where are you stuck?  You're viewing the code.  Have you tried writing any code?  Maybe start with an introductory tutorial?

Comment: I don't know how to link the pop-up message event with the "click" I make on the menu.

Comment: @Marko: Start with an introductory tutorial on Windows Forms development.  For your own reference, the language you're using is C#.  (This will help you find an applicable tutorial, so you don't get confused by a Visual Basic tutorial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work for what your asking. If you are on your form you can double click the button you want to interact with, and Visual Studio should take you to the empty method.

```
private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is supposed to be helpful");
    }
```

Comment: Is there any more complex message box, with decision options maybe, or something like that?

Comment: start doing a google search @Marko come on .. do you want us to also write the entire application for you...?

Comment: @Marko for that I would have my message box open another form. On that form I would add in whatever utilities I wanted/needed.

Comment: @Marko Sorry in the above comment I said have the message box open another form. What I meant was have the help button open another form. You would do that in the same method where you put the message box.